# Use of external authentication provider for user credentials, private IdentityServer for token generation

Tags: .net, api, azure, authentication, identityserver4

I am designing a security backend which is supposed to provide tokens for several clients in order to protect a number of APIs. The user database is in Azure B2C https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/. 
I want to create API tokens that contains different claims based on user access. E.g: User A should be able to call /api/stores/11, but not /api/stores/12.

Use cases:

- An app (ipad) that goes directly to Azure B2C for user login and token generation. Use this token to call APIs for user profile social interaction etc.
- External systems who will call the same APIs (different modules) with access rights limitations. The external systems will have administrators who will also get credentials from Azure B2C.

My solution so far:

1. IdentityServer4 (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) that calls Azure B2C login to verify user credentials.
2. Once authentication is complete (on callback), the IdentityServer will apply whichever claims the user has (access rights etc) for the external systems, then generate a token. IdentityServer will have a local database that connects userid/emails with access rights.
3. APIs will use multi-tenant authentication providers to support BOTH a token from Azure B2C AND my "in-between" IdentityServer. The providers are IdentityServerAuthentication and OpenIdConnectAuthentication respectively.

My question is if this is a viable solution? Is it too complicated? What would you do differently in this case? I don't want to implement a second user login, and Azure B2C doesnt seem to support fine-grained access rights.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a very common architecture.

The core identity and token platform is owned by **you** - and that is the only sane thing to do.

You can then use whatever mechanism (in your case Azure B2C) to do authentication. You might want to add a local database with users or some other authentication mechanism in the future. And that's totally fine.

The important point is - your applications don't care about that. All they know is your platform (in your case built using identityserver). If you decide one day you need to change your authentication provider - that's fine. Your applications are shielded from that fact.

At this point, your apps and services only need to trust the tokens coming from identityserver - identityserver takes care of brokering the trust with the external parties.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My only concern then is how do app users sign in/up from their native apps if the app will point to ID4? ID4 will then redirect to Azure B2C then they probably won't get sent back to the app. I dont know much about native app behavior so im sorry if I'm unclear.

Comment: ID4 will be transparent in the middle. All a matter of configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is very doable with IdentityServer4. Your use cases can be catered for. I would suggest checking out the [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples).

Comment: Thanks, I've checked out the samples, and the one using Google Auth has the same setup. I was wondering whether you would go for that in a production environment. That would mean checking for Google token as well as ID4 token.

Comment: Its a fairly normal pattern. You are relying on other (trusted) identity providers for user claims for your application needs. In your case you would use what Azure B2C asserts to be true about the current user in your application.

Comment: What do you mean with "That would mean checking for Google token as well as ID4 token"? See my answer.

Comment: @leastprivilege by that I meant multi-tenancy in the API.